# Airflow Docker Operator returning sucess when python code inside fail

Tags: python, docker, containers, airflow

I'm a pretty new dev in the docker world and at this point I really need help.

I have a python script inside a docker container.  When python exits with `sys.exit(-1)` the docker container still exits with success and consequently mark success in airflow too, omitting real errors and trace-backs.

How can I exit from container with error ?

Comment: Can you please share both a snippet of your script and your Dockerfile? Otherwise, I don't think that you can get any help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I just figured out the answer myself.

First, remove any old images that airflow might be using. List them with `docker images`, and then remove with `docker rmi <image_id>`

Now, in your code add a sys.exit(1) in a try/except for the main part of the code that is getting called by the DAG.

Comment: Don't you have to do anything else within the DAGs?

Answer (score 0):

First, set `remove=True` to your docker container, so it's automatically removed when it's finished running. Second, use python's `try:except:` in both your python code and your DAG to catch the exceptions. And last - raise `AirflowException` in the DAG, so Airflow can detect the issue and mark the task as ***failed***.

1. In your DAG:

   ```
    from airflow.exceptions import AirflowException

    try:
        client = docker.from_env()
        response = client.containers.run(image, command, remove=True, ...)
        ...
    except Exception as e:
        raise AirflowException(e)
   ```
2. In your python code:

   ```
    import logging

    try:
        ...
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(e)
   ```